# The language identifier example in the "How to format" box doesn't work for python

Tags: bug, code-formatting, markdown-rendering

Currently, the "How to format" box in the edit window has the example language identifier

````
```python
  def function(foo):
    print(foo)
```
````

Which produces the non-hilighted output

```python
  def function(foo):
    print(foo)
```

It should be

````
```lang-python
  def function(foo):
    print(foo)
```
````

Which has the properly highlighted output

```python
  def function(foo):
    print(foo)
```

As per [Cerbrus' answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388576/4037594) this works for some (most?) languages.

I have seen the bug happen with Java as well, although that didn't happen when I tried to reproduce it here;

java:

```java
public static void foo(){
}
```

lang-java:

```java
public static void foo(){
}
```

**I'm editing this question to see if the [switch to hilight.js](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter?cb=1) has changed things. (It has)**

Answer (score 6):

The `lang-` key is optional:

````
```lang-js
function test( ){
  return null;
}
```
````

```js
function test( ){
  return null;
}
```

Versus:

````
```js
function test( ){
  return null;
}
```
````

```js
function test( ){
  return null;
}
```

So this might be an alias / configuration issue specific to [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python).